# 'Text-decoration: none !important' not working with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my codepen: https://codepen.io/LastSoldi3r/pen/OmjGgR

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/1ade2ea03e.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i> Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about"><i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#portfolio"><i class="fa fa-folder-open" aria-hidden="true"></i> Portfolio</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-address-book" aria-hidden="true"></i> Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="container-fluid" style="margin-left: 10%; padding: 1px ;">
  <a name="home">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <img width="100%" height="100%" class="code" src="http://cdn2.cloudpro.co.uk/sites/cloudprod7/files/java_0.jpg">
        <img class="nametag" src="http://i.imgur.com/12ZcxYW.png">
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>

<div class="container-fluid  text" style="margin-left: 10%; padding: 1px 16px;"> 
  <!--About Me-->
  <a name="about">
    <h2 align="center">About</h2><br>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <p id="aboutMe">I earned my Associates of Science for Information Technology in 2015.  I am now working on my certification in Front End Web Development with the end goal of being a certified Full Stack Web Developer.  I am achieving this goal with the help of freeCodeCamp().</p>
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h2 align="center">Skills</h2><br>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 skills">
      <i class="fa fa-coffee"></i>
      <p>JAVA</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 skills">
      <i class="fa fa-html5"></i>
      <p>HTML5</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 skills">
      <i class="fa fa-css3"></i>
      <p>CSS3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 skills">
      <i class="fa fa-code"></i>
      <p>JAVASCRIPT</p>
    </div>
  </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img width="50%" height="50%" src="https://scontent.fhsv1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/15219976_10153891163957294_6687591802937802260_n.jpg?oh=dccd86082954a5d9d1764fbd53ad70dc&oe=5982B68A">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--Portfolio-->
    <br><br>
    <a name="portfolio">
      <div class="well background">
        <h2 align="center">Portfolio</h2><br>
      </div>


</div>    
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
background-color: #011f4b !important;
margin: 0;
}

ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 10%;
background-color: #b3cde0;
position: fixed;
height: 100%;
overflow: auto;
}

li a {
display: block;
color: #000;
padding: 8px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

li a.active {
background-color: #005b96;
color: white;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
background-color: #6497b1;
color: white;
}

#aboutMe {
font-size: 20px;
}

.code {
position: relative;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}

.nametag {
position: absolute;
top: 35px;
left: 60px;
}

.skills {
text-align: center;
font-size: 1.7em;
width: 110%;
}

.background {
background-color: #03396c !important;
}
```

I understand that you can change the css within bootstrap itself to change these effects.  However, I am learning and seeing as I am new I just used the link provided on the bootstrap website instead of sifting through the css.  If you look at my pen you will see that hovering over any text well darken it and underline some parts.

I have tried overriding the code in various ways.

My most recently tried, and most commonly found solution:

```
a.hover {text-decoration: none !important;}
```

This has not worked for me and I haven't been able to find any other working solution.

Comment: Chrome dev tools will help you easily solve problems like this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were super close!

```
li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #6497b1;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Here is a forked example of what you are looking for:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NjaobY

Comment: Thank you so much!

I have one more question, how would I apply this to the text in my 'About' section?

I tried putting the same code under:

    #about me{font-size: 20px; text-decoration: none;}

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XReOev this fork has text decoration disabled for all `<a>` tags thought your original question only applied to the nav

Comment: I have been trying to fix the effects for the whole page.  I should've specified that in my question :/.  I tried using what you showed me directed at my <p> tags but with no effect.

Comment: should be as simple as `html p { text-decoration: none;}` try messing with the styling in chrome dev tools should solve all your problems...

Answer (score 1):

add this simple code to your css file :

```
html a:hover {
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

here is how your page will shown :

```css
html a:hover {
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
body {
  background-color: #011f4b !important;
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 10%;
  background-color: #b3cde0;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a.active {
  background-color: #005b96;
  color: white;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #6497b1;
  color: white;
}

#aboutMe {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.code {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.nametag {
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  left: 60px;
}

.skills {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  width: 110%;
}

.background {
  background-color: #03396c !important;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/1ade2ea03e.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="active" href="#home"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i> Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about"><i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#portfolio"><i class="fa fa-folder-open" aria-hidden="true"></i> Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-address-book" aria-hidden="true"></i> Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    
    <div class="container-fluid" style="margin-left: 10%; padding: 1px ;">
      <a name="home">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <img width="100%" height="100%" class="code" src="http://cdn2.cloudpro.co.uk/sites/cloudprod7/files/java_0.jpg">
            <img class="nametag" src="http://i.imgur.com/12ZcxYW.png">
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        
    <div class="container-fluid  text" style="margin-left: 10%; padding: 1px 16px;"> 
      <!--About Me-->
      <a name="about">
        <h2 align="center">About</h2><br>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <p id="aboutMe">I earned my Associates of Science for Information Technology in 2015.  I am now working on my certification in Front End Web Development with the end goal of being a certified Full Stack Web Developer.  I am achieving this goal with the help of freeCodeCamp().</p>
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <h2 align="center">Skills</h2><br>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 skills">
          <i class="fa fa-coffee"></i>
          <p>JAVA</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 skills">
          <i class="fa fa-html5"></i>
          <p>HTML5</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 skills">
          <i class="fa fa-css3"></i>
          <p>CSS3</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 skills">
          <i class="fa fa-code"></i>
          <p>JAVASCRIPT</p>
        </div>
      </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <img width="50%" height="50%" src="https://scontent.fhsv1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/15219976_10153891163957294_6687591802937802260_n.jpg?oh=dccd86082954a5d9d1764fbd53ad70dc&oe=5982B68A">
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--Portfolio-->
        <br><br>
        <a name="portfolio">
          <div class="well background">
            <h2 align="center">Portfolio</h2><br>
          </div>
        
        
    </div>    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just added `text-decoration: none` to your existing CSS. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Lyzqxp

Comment: How would I get rid of the same effect in my 'About' section?  Thank you for your help?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `a.hover` with `a:hover` and it should work.

- **.hover** means "class named hover"
- **:hover** means "when the element is hovered"

If you're using Chrome, the Developper Tools (right click -> inspect element) -or similar firebug features- will allow you to see what css is being rendered on any element.

Answer (score 0):

```
you should override bootstrap style by "!important" please use this:
```

https://codepen.io/houtan/pen/mmBvop

Comment: Your solution should be included in your answer.  It's fine to link to external demonstrations, but the basic response should be inline on the page.  What happens if codepen goes out of business?